# Making sure my extended lists always show "current" data?

Tags: tridion

When you create a Data Extender for a CME list – for instance to add a column for the Schema as in [this example](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_E4EFBE6E5CA24C01B2531FB15AE95AE2) – it all works fine and dandy whenever you do actions that force a List reload.

However, some actions don’t force a list reload (like editing a component in a folder, then saving & closing) and it looks like Anguilla is loading the data for the item that changed using a different mechanism that loads only the data for the item in question (which makes sense).

If I would want my extended list view to behave properly and also load my additional attributes whenever a given item changes (instead of only when the list view is reloaded) what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found how Anguilla takes care of this. When you implement a Data Extender, you are extending the information regarding the items displayed in the list, which basically means that you are extending the Data (Model) behind the item in question.

Each Item in Tridion has its own class in the Anguilla Framework, for example a Component has its own Tridion.ContentManager.Component javascript "class".

Having said this, and going back to the example that shows the schema name of the component, we are not actually extending the model, since that information is already available in the component. However, we need to overwrite the methods exposed on each used for displaying information in the lists the item is in, in this case a Component.

So, when we deal with a Data Extender, if we want a full implementation of this functionality, we not only need to define the data extender:

```
<ext:dataextender 
    name="IntelligentDataExtender" 
    type="Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.IntelligentDataExtender,PS.GUI.Extensions">
    <ext:description>Shows extra info</ext:description>
</ext:dataextender>
```

But also we need to define what's the column we are adding:

```
<ext:lists>
    <ext:add>
        <ext:extension name="IntelligentColumnExtender"   
                       assignid="IntelligentDataColumnExtender">
          <ext:listDefinition>
            <ext:selectornamespaces/>
            <ext:columns>
              <column 
                  xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/List"
                  id="IntelligentData" 
                  type="data"  
                  title="Additional Info" 
                  selector="@ExtendedInfo" 
                  translate="String"/>
            </ext:columns>
          </ext:listDefinition>
          <ext:apply>
            <ext:view name="DashboardView" />
          </ext:apply>
        </ext:extension>
      </ext:add>
  </ext:lists>
```

Once we have this, the GUI will display the column we just added: "Additional Info"

Well, now we need to achieve the list refreshing when the item is edited/checked-out and in, etc...

For that, we need to extend the model and implement a few methods in the Object we are extending. In this example I am extending the Page object, so whenever a page is edited, the row in the list we want to update gets refreshed, together with the rest of the cells in the table.

To extend the model we need to define what types are we extending, in this example I am going to use the "Page" class as an example. First of all you need to define the model extension in the config file of your Editor:

```
<cfg:group name="Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.Model"
     merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.DomainModelProcessor" 
     merge="always">
    <cfg:domainmodel name="Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.Model">
      <cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/PSPage.js</cfg:file>            
      </cfg:fileset>
      <cfg:services />
    </cfg:domainmodel>
</cfg:group>
```

and

```
<ext:modelextensions>
  <cfg:itemtypes>
    <cfg:itemtype id="tcm:64" implementation="Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.PSPage" />        
  </cfg:itemtypes>
</ext:modelextensions>
```

As you can see I am extending the Page by using the "Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.PSPage" class that is defined in the Javascript file "/Scripts/PSPage.js".

The only method that handles the row refreshing is the following:

```
Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.PSPage.prototype.getListItemXmlAttributes 
= function PSPage$getListItemXmlAttributes(customAttributes) {
    var attribs = {};
    var p = this.properties;   

    if (customAttributes) {
        for (var attr in customAttributes) {
            attribs[attr] = customAttributes[attr];
        }
    }
    //This adds my custom column back when the item is updated
    attribs["ExtendedInfo"] = p.extendedInfo;

    return this.callBase(
        "Tridion.ContentManager.Page", 
        "getListItemXmlAttributes", 
        [attribs])
};
```

As you can see I am implementing the "ExtendedInfo" attribute which is the one displayed in my additional column.

There's more than just adding a Data Extender when dealing with adding a column to our lists. I will write a post in [my blog here](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2012/04/sdl-tridion-2011-data-extenders-real.html) to provide with a fully working example.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for providing a example for Data Extenders. I am trying to create a Data Extender which should fill the list field of my component taking the values from the look up component. For that I am able to establish a core service connection just by adding a new binding of type basic http. I am succeeded in establishing the connection. I don't know about service reference. Is it compulsory to have it? How to point to a particular field of component page through Data Extenders to populate it? Please explain me. Thanks in advance. Early response is appreciated.

Comment: @jaime I know is a long time from the post...but I'm using web8 and still having the same problem of the refresh. I don't get where should we put the javascript files on the server...

Comment: Check my blog, I have a full example there, http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2012/04/sdl-tridion-2011-data-extenders-real.html, to fully implement the data extender, you need the data extender as well as the GUI extension part.

Answer (score 6):

Well, Jaime correctly described how CME updates changed items in Lists. But I want to add some additional information on how List controls, domain model List and Items are interact with each other. This might help you building your own extension with similar functionality.

Most of the domain model List items inherit from `Tridion.ContentManager.ListTcmItems` class. On the moment when any List item, based on mentioned class, is loaded it will be registered in Lists Registry (and un-registered when the List is unloaded). This will allow Model to use registered Lists as source of static data for Items and to update changed Items data in these Lists.

**Update Item static data**

For example, we have loaded ListCategories and there is only one Category in the List:

```
var pub = $models.getItem("tcm:0-1-1");
var list = pub.getListCategories();
list.load();

// After list is loaded
list.getXml();
```

That `getXml()` returns an XML like (simplified):

```
<tcm:ListCategories>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:1-4-512" Type="512" Title="Keys" />
</tcm:ListCategories>
```

After that, if you try to get some static data for Category "Keys" it will be already set:

```
var category = $models.getItem("tcm:1-4-512");
category.isLoaded();         // return false
category.isStaticLoaded();   // return false
category.getTitle();         // return undefined
category.getStaticTitle();   // return "Keys"!
```

That is possible because `$models.getItem` call will do two things: it will return an existing (or create a new) domain model object and call `$models.updateItemData` method with it. This method call will go through all registered Lists in the Lists Registry and for all Lists whose TimeStamp bigger than Item's Last Update TimeStamp will call `list.updateItemData` with the model object.

The `updateItemData` method will check if the passed Item is in the list and if it is, then the Item will be updated with the static data that is available from the List.

**Updating data of changed Items in the List**

When a domain model Item is modified (updated, removed, created new) one of these methods is called:

- `$models.itemUpdated`
- `$models.itemRemoved`

These methods will go through the Lists in Lists Registry and call `list.itemUpdated` (or `list.itemRemoved`). These methods will check is passed Item is contained in their List and if so they will update the List xml from the Item data.

For that purpose there is a `getListItemXmlNode` method in the `Tridion.ContentManager.Item` class. This method will build List xml node based on the array of attributes, provided by `getListItemXmlAttributes` method on the Item. That's what Jaime mentioned in his answer.

If the List xml was updated, one of these events will be fired on List object:

- itemadd
- itemupdate
- itemremove

Listening to these events on a `List` object in your view will allow you to timely update your List Control.

So if you want this mechanism to work with your extension, stick to these rules:

- If you are creating new domain model List object - it should inherit `Tridion.ContentManager.ListTcmItems` class or it should implement the `getId()`, `itemUpdated(item)`, `itemsUpdated(item)`, `itemRemoved(item)` and `updateItemData(item)` methods
- If you want to see changes in List control - attach handlers to corresponding events on the domain model List object and update your List control
- If you are creating new domain model Item - it should inherit `Tridion.ContentManager.Item` class and you should improve `getListItemXmlAttributes` method to return correct array of attributes for the List

Comment: Good stuff, Boris. A possible correction: wouldn't category.isStaticLoaded() return true in the given example?

Comment: @PeterKjaer No, it will be false because you have not loaded static data (loaded item's xml from CM with VIEW open mode). It's kind of exceptional case when some of the Item's data available when Item is not loaded.

Comment: Excellent answer Boris, we have proposed a dedicated Stack Exchange site for Tridion, and your expertise would be very useful, if you would consider following it? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion

Comment: Thanx for invitation. Following up now.

Answer (score 2):

The CME will indeed update the items in the list dynamically after the save occurs, without going to the server.

To do so, it calls a method named "getListItemXml" which returns the update  XML element for the list. It will then update or add this element, which will update or add the item in the list view.

getListItemXml is a method of the different Model objects.

So how do you take advantage of this? I'm not sure.

Perhaps you could overwrite the method (or maybe getListItemXmlAttributes is best) with your own to add the additional data?

There is also an "itemupdate" event fired whenever an item is updated in the list. 
You can hook into that by doing something like this:

```
var myEventHandler = function(event)
{
    $log.message("Item updated. TridionEvent object passed: " + event);
}

var view = $display.getView();
var list = view.getListObject("uri-of-Folder");
list.addEventListener("itemupdate", myEventHandler);
```

I suppose you could use that to update the list entry for the item after the fact. 
Be sure to call removeEventHandler at some point too.

None of this is optimal, obviously. 
But I don't know of any extension point that would solve this particular problem.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll accept this answer for now, since I can see it will work. I'm pretty sure there must be a "better" way which the CME uses, right?

Comment: This is the method the CME uses. The problem is that it doesn't have take extensibility into account. The item is updated just fine, with the data that the CME *knows* about; but there's no easy way to add the data that is added by an extension.

Comment: Indeed, there is no "easy" way, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would (attempt to) implement this by monitoring the items in a folder periodically and updating that list after this polling mechanism had detected a change in that folder.

For example, I would write some javascript timeout or interval that runs in the background and checks the items in the current folder. If it detects a change, it triggers the update of the list.

Alternatively, you could also try to intercept the action that changed your list (e.g. the creation of a new item), maybe by means of an event system, and as such update your list. I don't think this is much different than the first approach, as I think it still implies some level of polling from the GUI side.

Comment: That sounds like a work around for something that already exists (the CME handles it today).

Comment: Even if you go in applying this "work around", you don't need to implement it from scratch - in SP1 release there was introduced ListMonitoredItems (as part of TCM54 Model js code base). You can easily add items to this list and remove from it. Items in the list will be monitored with timeout set in configuration file. When one of the monitored items will be change - appropriate event will be fired.