# How to implement a Data Extender for populating a List in the component creation page?

Tags: c#, tridion

I am new to Data Extenders concept in the Tridion. I came to know that it requires a config file and cs file from online documentation of SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. Is there any need of using core services for that? Please explain me the steps. Thanks in advance. Early response is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Please read this excellent article from Jaime Santos Alcón:

http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2012/04/sdl-tridion-2011-data-extenders-real.html

It explains exactly which steps you need and which files are involved.

Comment: And Jaimes post is an answer to this Stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995335/making-sure-my-extended-lists-always-show-current-data/10030332#10030332. Might help you out as well

Comment: Hendrik Thank you for your response. Is there any alternative for core services?

Comment: No. If you want to access Tridion from a Data Extender, you must use the Core Service. It's not such a big deal as people seem to think. Just follow one of the many tutorials out there and first write a small (command line) program that uses the Core Service. Then you'll be better equipped to do the same inside a Data Extender.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your response. I tried to establish the connection using core services. It was successful. I gone through the jaime's post. My requirement is 1.Need to fetch a component 2.Loop through multivalued text fields 3. Populate those values to the component creation page GUI. Is it possible? Please help me out in this issue. Thanks in advance.