# Is it possible to default to 'main view' of the SDL Tridion 2011 CME instead of the dashboard?

Tags: tridion

SDL Tridion 2011 introduced the new dashboard (or control panel) in the CME. Under `User Preferences > View Settings` on that page, it is possible for a user to change their start-up view to load the main view rather than the dashboard. Is it possible to set this as a system wide setting for all users?

We are interested in doing this because we have a default custom  page that we want our editors to see, but this page is no longer loaded due to the dashboard being loaded by default.

Answer (score 6):

We can do this in per-user settings:

1. Set: `Screen Displayed after starting SDL Tridion` to Main View
2. Leave `Start on specific folder` unselected.
3. Right-click one a custom page and set it to `default`.

This user will now open Tridion on that default custom page.

However, I've seen organizations want to set this for *all* users without having to do it manually. I've been able to do so on my personal VM but can NOT recommend it for a production environment:

In `%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\CME.config`, set the following to an existing custom page URI.

```
<settings>
  <defaultpage>/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx#locationId=cme:0-1-custompg</defaultpage>
  <navigatorurl>/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx#locationId=cme:0-1-custompg</navigatorurl>
  ...
</settings>
```

So yes, it's *possible* to force a default for at least this version of SDL Tridion. But I'm not sure of a supported way.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, I just tried setting the defaultpage node to '/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx#locationId=cme:workitems' and now my GUI opens on the user work list. This is fantastic - Hopefully someone can chime in and tell us if this is supported - or a useful hack

Comment: That is the Editor config, which is not meant to be changed by customers. So changing that is not supported or probably a good idea in general.

Comment: Hi Peter, that was my initial thought as well. However, after furthe research there are a few items in that file which must be modified by a customer. Specifically, Environment Themes and SiteEdit target thumbnails. If we are allowed to change those, why not the default start page?

Comment: +1 to @Peter's point. It might be telling that the `theme` and and SiteEdit target settings are under `<customconfiguration>`. Theme specifically [has instructions to update it in the CME.config](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_C4C14E4D601B4BE392ACE3B067426BB7), but I don't see anything on the 'defaultpage.' This doesn't mean any other changes are specifically supported. I wonder if we can simply extend `<settings>` node in our own view?